# Visual Studio 2012 XAML Designer Exception

Tags: xaml, exception, designer

I'm trying to develop a windows store XAML application.  However, I get an error when I open the XAML designer.  The error is "System.Exception.  Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF3)"

It's just a new blank application.  It compiles and runs just fine.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8 Professional N x64.  VS is installed in the default directory with every module.  I've tried to re-install VS and repair it but was unable to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by regisering a developers account. I logged in via my @outlook.com and followed some simple steps after that which gave me a developers account for a month which made the error dissappear.

Hope it helps.